# Concatenation in SQL select query on Excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel

I have upload an Excel file now I want to read data from that sheet with a `select` query, and I want to concatenate 4 columns with separator `_` as Type_name

The query I  used is

```
select 
   *, '1' as fileid, 'Size' + '_' + 'Material' +'_' & 'Finishing' + '_' + 'Sides' as Type_Name  
from [sheet1$] 
where [Current Code] is not null or [Current Code] <> ''
```

All data is correctly returned by query except `Type_Name`

This query return `Type_Name` as `Size_Material_Finishing_Sides`

Comment: have a look into the `CONCAT()` function

Comment: You're **explicitly** telling your query to concatenate together these string literal values: `Size`, `_`, `Material`, `_`, `Finishing`, `_`, and `Sides` - so what did **you** expect to get from this ??

Comment: @marc_s - I think the point is the OP *wants* to get this result, but is not getting it.

Comment: @dan1111: not quite clear - I understood he's *getting* `Size_Material_Finishing_Sides` but really wants something else ....

Comment: @marc_s, I agree that it is not clear.

Comment: Size ,Material,Finishing,Sides are columns in Excel sheet i want concatinate value of these fields with seprator '_'

Comment: @user1817367: Quotation marks (`'`) are used to delimit string literals. If `Size`, `Material` et al. are names, then do not delimit them with `'`. I.e. it should probably look something like this: `Size + '_' + Material + '_' + ...`. And, as @dan111 has already pointed in their answer, you are using both `+` and `&` as concatenation operators. Shouldn't it be either one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of SQL you are using.

I assume you are querying from within Excel or from MS Access.  In this case you should use `String1 & String2 & ...`.

However, here are other options:

SQL Server uses `String1 + String2 + ...`.

Oracle, DB2, and some versions of MySQL use `String1 || String2 || ...`.

The method supported across the most versions of MySQL is `CONCAT(String1, String2, ...)`.

`CONCAT()` exists in most versions of SQL, but beware: you can't always use it to combine an arbitrary number of strings.  In Oracle and DB2, for example, this function can only combine two strings.

The example you posted includes a mixture of `+` and `&`, which definitely won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You are using & and + to concatenate? Why are you concatenating in the first place? Why not just use:

```
'Size_Material_Finishing_Sides' as Type_Name
```

If this is not the result you expected what result do you expect?

Comment: Presumably, this is just a simplified example, and the OP actually wants to concatenate some columns in the result.